# How can I serialize related fields and keep the HTML form a dropdown for foreign key fields?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I apologize if my question is confusing.

I have defined my serializers like this:

```
class VenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = "__all__"


class ConventionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    venue = VenueSerializer(read_only=False, many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Convention
        fields = "__all__"
```

I do get the desired JSON raw data:

```
{
    "venue": {
        "name": "",
        "address_1": "",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "",
        "state_province": "",
        "postal_code": "",
        "country": "",
        "webpage": ""
    },
    "name": "",
    "description": "",
    "webpage": "",
    "start_date": null,
    "end_date": null
}
```

However in the HTML form, instead of a dropdown for the venue (it is a foreign key), it gives the entire form for Venue.

Desired HTML form:
[image: Desired HTML form]

Resulting HTML form:
[image: Resulting HTML form]

Is there a way to set up the serializer so that I can return the JSON raw data above while also keeping the dropdown menu in the desired HTML form?

Also, when I completely remove the line `venue = VenueSerializer(read_only=False, many=False)` from `ConventionSerializer`, the dropdown menu will show in the HTML form, but my JSON data will return:

```
{
   "name": "",
    "description": "",
    "webpage": "",
    "start_date": null,
    "end_date": null,
    "venue": null
}
```

and if I set `read_only=True` for the `VenueSerializer`, it keeps the same JSON raw data, but it completely removes the venue option from the HTML form.

Comment: I usually have multiple serializers by view, some for reading and other for writing purposes. You can achieve this overwriting the `get_serializer_class` function in a `ViewSet` and assing the serializer based in the "action". In you case use one for get the diresed Json and other for writting only de pk in dropdown and thats is all.

Comment: If you provide you view code maybe I can elaborate more in this answer and offer some code to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
class VenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = "__all__"


class ConventionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    venue = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Venue.objects.all())
    #will generate a dropdown menu with the available Venue objects as options in the HTML form.
    class Meta:
        model = Convention
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: The dropdown in the HTML form appears when I do this, but the JSON data that comes back is

`{
    "venue": null,
    "name": "",
    "description": "",
    "webpage": "",
    "start_date": null,
    "end_date": null
}`

I want the venue field to be a venue object as well as having the dropdown in the HTML form.